# Efficiently loop over array, appending result to string

Tags: powershell, for-loop, windows-server-2019

I'm very much a Powershell beginner (if that). I've been stringing together code from everywhere to make something work, but now I want to make it a bit more manageable to edit.

I previously had this script which I had written out all, but it is very repetitive. It was a copy from source to destination, and was easy to control with 1-5 to do. I'm now up to 14, and it's a lot of repetitive code.

I'm trying to consolidate it into an easier to maintain script.

Previously, I was copying the `$copy` and `$result` lines multiple times for each share couple.

I've now moved that into an array which I want to loop over:

```
# shares to copy source and destination
# blank 1st entry for easier numbering
$shares = @(
  @(),
  @("\\nas01\share01\", "\\nas02\share01\"),
  ...
  @("\\nas01\share99\", "\\nas02\share99\"),
) 

# loop
for($parentLoop=1; $parentLoop -lt 99; $parentLoop++) {
  for($childLoop=0; $childLoop -lt 2 ; $childLoop++) {
    
    $args = '/cmd=sync /open_window /force_close "'+$shares[$parentLoop][0]+'" /to="'+$shares[$parentLoop][1]+'"'
    $copy   = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\FastCopy\FastCopy.exe" -ArgumentList $args -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
    $result = if( $copy.ExitCode -eq -1 ) { "FAILED" } else { "SUCCESS" }

    $source = [Math]::Round(("{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $shares[$parentLoop][0] -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum / 1GB) / 1024 ), 2) 
    $destination = [Math]::Round(("{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $shares[$parentLoop][1] -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum / 1GB) / 1024 ), 2) 
  }
  $response = "$result ( Source: $source / Destination: $destination )" 
}

# get the date time
$dateTime = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" 

# compile email
$emailBody = "Completed copy\n---\n\nShare 1: $response" 
$emailArgs = "-host:192.168.0.1:25 -from:email@domain.ltd `"-to:me@domain.ltd`" `"-subject:Copy report - $dateTime`" `"-body:$emailBody`""
$email = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\cMail\CMail.exe" -ArgumentList $emailArgs -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

What I don't know how to do is to add in the output of the `$response` for each loop into the `$emailBody`.

I also don't know if there is an easier way to get the share size. I thought about mounting the share (source and destination) then capturing it locally (`Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='A:'" | Select-Object Size`) and then unmounting it for the next loop, but wasn't sure it was efficient or if I'd run into issues of "failure to dismount".

Ideally, I'd like to be able to scale the `$shares` array up or down, and the email output to scale too. This was I can have a plaintext email (quicker to read than attachments) that says:

```
Completed copy
---

Share 1: SUCCESS (Source: 256 / Destination: 256)
...
Share 99: FAILURE (Source: 25 / Destination: 985)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$shares[1][1]` always point to `"\\nas02\share01\"`?  Are you trying to copy every network path to that one location?  The impression I have is that you are trying to copy from the share of the same name in nas01 to the same share in nas02, but you shouldn't need the inner loop of $childloop to do that, instead you should just refer to `$shares[$parentLoop][0]` and `$shares[$parentLoop][1]` as needed.

Comment: Ah shoot! You're correct @Darin, i'll update it